# Getting "define but not used" warning when using gcc "__thread" specifier

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, compiler-construction, thread-safety

I currently have a library with some global variables. I want to make these variables thread local so I added "__thread" specifier in front of them. It does the job but the compiler gives "define but not used" warnings on these variable. I hid the warnings with "-Wno-unused-variable", but I wonder why it happens because these variables are actually being used in the library.

Thanks!

Comment: Are they static or external?

Comment: @R.. They are static. And I think they are being used by the library functions and they do behave as intended after adding the "__thread" specifier. It's annoying to see those warnings and I wonder if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: If they're static then the only place it's even possible for them to be used is in the same `.c` file they're defined in. I suspect your library functions are using *different* global variables that just happen to have the same names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are really declared with `static`, as indicated in a comment, your compiler is probably right and this is just a waste of resources, since you are creating a new thread local variable in every compilation unit.

If you want that `static` allocation of global variables to change to sensible use of thread local variable, you'd have to do a bit more. Use a declaration as this

```
extern thread_local double eps;
```

in your header file and a definition

```
thread_local double eps;
```

in just one of your `.c` files.

Note also that thread local variables now are part of the C standard (C11) and that the keyword there is `_Thread_local`, with a standard "abbreviation" of `thread_local`. If your compiler doesn't support this yet, you can easily `#define` this conditionally to `__thread` or whatever compiler extension provides you with that feature.